Как развернуть свое asp .net приложение на сервере и получить к нему доступ с другого компа (все в локальной сети)?
Мне нужно развернуть api (asp .net) на сервере и подключиться к этому серверу с другой машины в локальной сети. Что я для этого сделал:

Прописал в appsettings.json следующее:
"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
"Http": { "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000" },
"Https": {
"Url": "https://0.0.0.0:5001"
      }
    }
  }


Собрал всё решение

Перешел в папку bin/Debug/net6.0

Запустил нужный мне exe файл




Перешел по ссылке https://ip:5001/swagger/index.html и получил ошибку


Нагуглил, что нужно открыть порты. Открыл, не помогло.


Как мне быть в этой ситуации?
